# How to check the format of a string in python?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to check the format of a string such as a registration plate, but I have no idea where to start.

I want the program to detect whether a string follows the format 'LLNN LLL', where L is a letter and N is a number.

I have seen multiple other questions about checking a string's format, but they where for a different programming language.

Comment: you can always code it yourself, look into regex.

Comment: This is a job for regular expressions, see the [regex howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching such as this is solved by **regular expressions**.

A *regular expression* – or *regex* – is a string defining a search pattern for use on other strings.

In python, they are covered by [the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html).

As an example, the following uses the set-matching `[]` to search for *either* an `a` or a `b`, followed by a `c`. It will return `None` in the first case, as it does not match `cc`. In the second case, one match is found: the `bc` between the `z`s and the `x`s. It would therefore evaluate to `True` in an `if` statement.

```
matches_none = re.search('[ab]c', 'cc')
matches_once = re.search('[ab]c', 'qqqzzzbcxxx')
```

As the Python docs state, there are certain special sequences which match sets or certain conditions. `\d`, for example, will match any digit, and `\w` will match any alphanumeric. All of the following find a match.

```
re.search('\w\d', '!!!54???')
re.search('\d\w', '!!5a?@#[ff')
re.search('[abc]\d\w', 'a5a')
```

There's a whole host of other features of regular expressions, including the ability to pick out matching groups, lookaheads, start- and end-of-string matching, and various ways of handling counts and multiplicity.

Answer (score -1):

I think this what you are looking for

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: temp = 'LL22 LLL'

In [3]: re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d\d [a-zA-Z]+',temp)
Out[3]: ['LL22 LLL']
```

Comment: An explanation of what regexps are would have been more helpful than just a code snippet solving the problem at hand without any explanation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers already 1st answer was a explanation of regular expression. Answering some thing doesn't make any sense. Therefore I wrote a solution for a problem

Comment: Then you might have posted this as a comment to the first answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry I am new to stackoverflow but I don't know how to post multi-line code as comment..